# accidentally deleted /etc/resolv.conf and now cannot access any domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on my dell inspiron 5402.I was annoyed about my unstable wifi,so I followed some method on the Internet and unfortunately got this problem.

Now when I open chrome, there is **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD__CONFIG** displayed.
I checked my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and it showed  `broken symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolv/stub.resolv.conf`,but when I checked the `/run/systemd/` directory ,there was no `resolv`.

I get fully confused and don't know what to do next .

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so please ask on http://askubuntu.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this to revert your dns config

```
resolvectl revert INF-NAME
```

it could revert back your dns config per-interfaces